Is there a standard function for performing a move-or-copy in c++?
I have a function which takes an rvalue reference:
void foo(int&& x);

I would like to create another function which supplies a universal interface with the original function:
template <class T> void use_foo(T&& x);

The idea is to either move x if it is an rvalue reference, or to copy it if it is a const reference or a rvalue.
std::forward doesn't work here since it can't ever copy the value. Is there such a function? If there isn't, how would I write one?

Consider passing the argument by value instead: it will be moved if possible, else copied.

Use overload void use_foo(Obj& o) {foo(Obj(o));} void use_foo(Obj&& o) {foo(std::move(o));} ?

I tried this, but it only works for the single argument version. When using functions with more than a single argument overloading for each possibility becomes quite complicated.

"const reference or a rvalue" you meant lvalue here, right?

What's wrong with std::remove_reference_t<T>  {std::forward<T>(t)}?

You can do it with an if constexpr like this:
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename type_t>
void f(type_t&& value)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(value)>)
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue reference\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "not an rvalue reference\n";
    }
}

struct X {};

int main()
{
    int value{42};
    int& ref{value};

    f(X{});
    f(value);
    f(ref);
}

outputs :
rvalue reference
not an rvalue reference
not an rvalue reference


decltype(value) is type_t&&, so you can also write std::is_rvalue_refernce_v<type_t&&> (Though personally I prefer !std::is_lvalue_reference_v<type_t> for this)

@Artyer Fair comments

I have found the answer to this question. There is no standard library function to do this I am aware of, but a function which does this can be written as follows:
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> concept is_non_const_rvalue_reference = std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T> && !std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

namespace
{
    template <class T> using to_rvalue_return_t = std::conditional_t<is_non_const_rvalue_reference<T>, T&&, std::decay_t<T>>;
}

template <class T> constexpr to_rvalue_return_t<T> to_rvalue(std::remove_reference_t<T>& v) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(v);
}

template <class T> constexpr to_rvalue_return_t<T> to_rvalue(std::remove_reference_t<T>&& v) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(v);
}

Using this function like std::forward turns any value into an rvalue, either by copying or moving it.
